# sql parent child relationship query

Tags: sql-server

I am having a customer table with following columns

```
 CustomerID, CustomerName, ParentCustomerID
```

How to get the customer who has the most number of children from this table?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, though I doubt it's the most efficient way of doing it.

Also I haven't run this myself, so it may need a little massage to get it to work. :)

```
select customerId, CustomerName
from
    customers
where customerId = (
    select top 1 ParentCustomerID 
    from
        customers
    group by ParentCustomerID
    order by count(*) desc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want this.

```
select top 1
    PARENT.CustomerID,
    NumberOfChildren = count(CHILD.CustomerID)
from customers PARENT
left join customers CHILD on PARENT.CustomerID = CHILD.ParentCustomerID
group by PARENT.CustomerID 
order by NumberOfChildren desc
```

This avoids the need for sub-queries by left joining the table to itself and can be quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
;WITH CTE( ChildCount, ParentCustomerID)
AS
(
  SELECT 
          COUNT(customerID) ChildCount,
          ParentCustomerID 
  FROM TABLE 
  GROUP BY ParentCustomerID
)
SELECT TABLE.CustomerId, TABLE.CustomerName
FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN TABLE 
ON 
TABLE.CustomerId = CTE.ParentCustomerID
AND 
CTE.ChildCount = (SELECT MAX(ChildCount) FROM CTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Stamtent to solve the problem

```
SELECT TOP 1 ParentCustomerID, COUNT(customerID)
FROM customer 
GROUP BY ParentCustomerID
```